# Snowflake - simulate a long-running query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to easily simulate that query runs in a minimum of time and still returns an output?

If possible, generating fake data with "cross join" or changing virtual warehouse size should be avoided, as it only produces "noise".

The goal is to test timeouts and/or connection handling on the user application side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake Data Cloud offers [SYSTEM$WAIT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_wait) function which can be easily combined with actual query without affecting final result

Example:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.REGION AS r;
-- output of only 5 rows generated in miliseconds
/*
R_REGIONKEY R_NAME  R_COMMENT
0   AFRICA  lar deposits. requests. regular accounts are according to 
1   AMERICA hs use ironic, even requests. s
2   ASIA    ges. thinly even pinto beans ca
3   EUROPE  ly final courts cajole furiously final excuse
4   MIDDLE EAST uickly special
*/
```

Simulating 30 second delay by applying `LATERAL (SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(30)) AS delay` on the  outermost query.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.REGION AS r
,LATERAL (SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(30)) AS delay;
```

Output:

[image]

---

Alternatively taking into account that `SYSTEM$WAIT` returns a row - `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(n))`:

```
SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.REGION
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(10));
```

The `WHERE` approach could be combined with DML:

```
UPDATE tab_name
SET col = 1
WHERE col = ...
  AND EXISTS (SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(10));


DELETE FROM tab_name
WHERE col = ...
  AND EXISTS (SELECT SYSTEM$WAIT(10));
```